# Is there an existing plugin for jQuery that counts down to a specific time, then counts back up?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, timer

I'm looking for an existing plugin (before I bother writing it) that counts down in days, hours, minutes, and seconds to a specific time, then upon reaching 0 begins to count up from it.  Nothing fancy, just text is fine.

An existing tutorial or closely related project works as well.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html which can count down and up.
You'll have to change manually though

```
$('#countdown').countdown({
    until: liftoffTime, 
    onExpiry: function(){
        var startTime = new Date();
        $('#countdown').countdown({since: startTime});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this one, he's good and customizable :

http://www.littlewebthings.com/projects/countdown/

Comment: How would one go about allowing it to count up?